# SQL Permissions Levels Needed to Deploy SQL CLR

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I'm trying to deploy a quick test of a locally developed C# SQL-CLR stored procedure and assemblies to a DEV box and am getting various denied access messages.

> The reverse engineering operation cannot continue because you do not
>   have View Definition permission on the database.

**Q:** What permissions group or level do I need on the server to deploy SQL CLR?

**Q:** The message above implies `DDLAdmin`, but do I need any more?

**VERSION:** Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64)

I'm having trouble getting a list of minimum permissions needed from folks at work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Post error messages, could be from database or from windows server

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2012+, is this project deployment model or package deployment model? If package deployment model, where are you deploying the SSIS packages to?

Comment: I decided to restrict the question to SQL CLR & ask the SSIS question separately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The message above implies `DDLAdmin`

No, it doesn't imply that. It clearly states that the Login needs `VIEW DEFINITION`. While `ddl_admin` might work, it might be much more than is necessary. However, that being said, why aren't you deploying as a privileged account? I have rarely, if ever, seen a deployment process that didn't run as `sysadmin`. That and how are you not a sysadmin on a dev box? ;-)

There are two issues at hand:

1. The SSDT process which does the reverse-engineering so that it can come up with an incremental deployment script, but is not making any changes at this point, and
2. the act of publishing / deploying the script once it is generated.

Your error is about part 1, but the question is, at least in how it is worded, about both parts.

So to address part 2, you need `CREATE` permission (whether per object, or on the schema, or via a fixed DB role like `ddl_admin`) to create the objects. You also need to be able to `ALTER` the Assembly. Regarding the ALTER permissions for the Assembly, the MSDN page for [ALTER ASSEMBLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186711.aspx) states:

> Requires ALTER permission on the assembly. Additional requirements are as follows:
>
> - To alter an assembly whose existing permission set is EXTERNAL_ACCESS, requires **EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY** permission on the server.
> - To alter an assembly whose existing permission set is UNSAFE requires **UNSAFE ASSEMBLY** permission on the server.
> - To change the permission set of an assembly to EXTERNAL_ACCESS, requires **EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY** permission on the server. To change the permission   set of an assembly to UNSAFE, requires **UNSAFE ASSEMBLY** permission on the server.
> - Specifying WITH UNCHECKED DATA, requires **ALTER ANY SCHEMA** permission.

IF the Assembly is to be created with a `PERMISSION_SET` of either `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE`, then *prior to* creating the Assembly, you should have signed the Assembly (might be a good idea in any case), then create an Asymmetric Key in `[master]` from that Assembly, then create a Login from that Asymmetric Key, and finally grant that Login either `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` or `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY`. Do *not* set the DB containing the Assembly to `TRUSTWORTHY ON` unless you absolutely must, such as in the case of loading an unsupported .NET Framework library since you cannot re-sign those.

For a step-by-step guide on handling the creation of the Asymmetric Key and Login while using Visual Studio / SSDT, please see the 3-part article I publish on SQL Server Central that addresses this and other nuances of VS and SSDT:

[Stairway to SQLCLR Level 6: Development Tools Intro](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/138154/) (free registration is required by this site).

Level 7 specifically deals with the security / Asymmetric Key / Login stuff, but it might be best to start with Level 6 as it is the setup for Levels 7 and 8 (it was really one long article that had to be broken up ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error message while trying to deploy a SQL database using **SQL Server database deploy** task in Azure DevOps Release pipelines. The issue was that the user account being used to do the deployment did not have the necessary permissions. Adding **all of the below roles** to the user account fixed the issue :

- db_datareader
- db_datawriter
- db_ddladmin
- db_executor
- db_owner

Comment: Just the "db_owner" has all the required permissions, they is no need to all the other roles.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly owner must be the user that you are using to deploy the assembly or the owner must be a role in which that user is a member.

Deployment of a 'safe' permission set assembly needs the following:

- db_DDLAdmin - this permission grants CREATE and ALTER permissions for the assemblies and objects types that you deploy
- database-level VIEW DEFINITION - required in order to deploy
- database-level CONNECT - grants the ability to connect to the database

Deployment of an 'external_access' permission or 'unsafe' permission set assembly needs the following additional permissions:

- TRUSTWORTHY database option set to ON
- The login that you use to deploy must have the Unsafe Assembly or External Access server permission.

Ref:
[Required Permissions for SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj889462%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#SQLCLRPermissions)

Comment: It is absolutely not true that the `TRUSTWORTHY` database option needs to be `ON`. Only in rare cases is it required, mainly when loading already-signed, 3rd party DLLs that you cannot re-sign (the typical case is unsupported .NET Framework libraries). It is a very bad practice to set TRUSTWORTHY to ON unless there is absolutely no other way.

Comment: I agree, I would be VERY hesitant to turn that option on.  Certainly a last resort. However, that's what MSDN was saying, so I included it.

Comment: I just looked and see that it is what it written there, but it is quite specifically incorrect. Hence that advice should not be propagated here. The permissions requirements are more complex, and are stated explicitly when you try to load an UNSAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS assembly without having TRUSTWORTHY ON or the signature and key and login. Also, I do not believe it is correct about the assembly owner needing to be the one deploying the assembly, but I only deploy as a sysadmin so haven't tested that.